# UITableViewCell custom selectedBackgroundView issue

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview

So I'm facing an issue with setting a custum selectedBackgroundView inside my `UITableViewCell`.

My cell has a `contentView` that basically is a `UIView` (frame = 0,0,80,70) with a black background and an `UIImageView` as a subview.

The imageView's `contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;`

This looks something like this:

[image: unselected cells]

Now I set the selectedBackgroundView like this:

```
    //set the custom selected color
    UIView *bgColorView                 = [[UIView alloc] init];
    bgColorView.backgroundColor         = MY_TINT_COLOR;
    CGColorRef darkColor                = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha: 0.25].CGColor;
    CGColorRef lightColor               = [self.view.backgroundColor colorWithAlphaComponent:0.0].CGColor;
    //setting some gradients here
    //should not be relevant for the question
    [cell setSelectedBackgroundView:bgColorView];
```

This results in something like this:

[image]

My question now is why the `selectedBackgroundView` hides the black part of the `contentView`?

I have already tried initializing my `bgColorView` with a frame starting at `x = 80`, but this does not change anything.

Also I have tried to explictly set the `backgroundColor` of the `imageView` to black, same result.

What could cause this behaviour?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Following figure gives the idea of a cell structure. The selected Background view will hide Content view

[image]

So you can give a try by setting background color of cell as black.
Your custom cell looks something like this

```
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor]; // Gives black background for you


    // Set selected background view
    UIView *backgroundView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:self.bounds];
    backgroundView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor colorWithRed:0.529 green:0.808 blue:0.922 alpha:1]CGColor];
    backgroundView.layer.borderWidth = 10.0f;
    self.selectedBackgroundView = backgroundView;
    [backgroundView release];

    // Set the content view
    CGRect frame  = CGRectMake(self.bounds.origin.x+5, self.bounds.origin.y+5, self.bounds.size.width-10, self.bounds.size.height-10);
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    self.imageView = imageView;
    [imageView release];
    self.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill ;
    self.imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.imageView];
```

Comment: Thank you for your helpfull answer! I did not know about the cell's view hierarchy. Setting the `contentView` to a `UIImageView` solved the problem :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, helped me alot!

Comment: I dont get it. From the diagram, contentview is most top, so why would setting selectedbackgroundview cover the contentview?

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try overriding

```
- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted animated:(BOOL)animated
```

and

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
```

of UITableViewCell class to get the desired behavior.

Comment: Hm I was hoping not to need to subclass UITableViewCell. Anyway I will give it a try and tell you a if it was successfull. Thanks so far!